# Random crash in NTDLL.dll with PlaneProjection animation - WinRT/Metro

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I was trying to build a simple "scrolling road" animation for Windows 8/Store/Metro/whatever it's called today, but keep getting an intermittent crash.

Here is some code to reproduce, just create a new blank Windows Store VB project (In VS2012 or 2013), and replace OnNavigatedTo in MainPage.xaml.vb with this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(e As Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)
    Dim _rnd As New Random()
    Dim g As Grid = Me.Content
    g.Children.Clear()

    Dim updates As New List(Of Action)

    Dim iDepth = 20
    Dim iWidth = 4
    Dim midP = (iWidth / 2) + 0.5
    ' Add images
    For x = 1 To iWidth
        For y = 0 To iDepth - 1
            Dim img As New Image With {.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill, .Source = New BitmapImage(New Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png")), .VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Center, .HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Center, .Width = 100, .Height = 100}
            g.Children.Add(img)

            Dim pp As New PlaneProjection()
            img.Projection = pp

            pp.LocalOffsetX = (x - midP) * 100
            pp.LocalOffsetY = -(y * 100)
            pp.RotationX = -75
            pp.GlobalOffsetZ = 900

            updates.Add(Sub()
                            pp.LocalOffsetY += 2

                            If pp.LocalOffsetY >= 100 Then
                                pp.LocalOffsetY = (iDepth - 1) * -100
                            End If
                        End Sub)

        Next
    Next

    AddHandler CompositionTarget.Rendering, Sub()
                                                For Each aFN In updates
                                                    aFN()
                                                Next
                                            End Sub
End Sub
```

Let it run for a minute or two and it should crash eventually. NOTE depending on values of iDepth and iWidth can affect time before crash (or sometimes not at all). Try 6 and 6 which crashes fast for me.
Here is info from Event log:

Faulting application name: XAMLBenchmark.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x50f5de60

Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x5010aeb6

Exception code: 0xc0000374

Fault offset: 0x000ce881

Faulting process id: 0xe98

Faulting application start time: 0x01cdf3736fe85fea

Faulting application path: 
H:\Programming\Projects\Test\XAMLBenchmark\bin\Debug\AppX\XAMLBenchmark.exe

Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

Report Id: c940b610-5f66-11e2-afa1-00247e0381dc

Faulting package full name: 5c4576c8-cee9-410d-adcc-92242ee8ba45_1.0.0.0_neutral__eg50eqkjtk654

Faulting package-relative application ID: App

Any thoughts on what is the underlying cause of crash?

Comment: I'm facing the same exception 01/2019, latest Visual Studio 2019 Preview... hey, M$!